# proc http headerin option

Tags: rest, http, sas, proc

i am trying to connect to Salesforce via REST API from sas(using `proc http`).

The issue I face is:
it can not recsolve swedish character.

so i found something like:

```
"Accept: */*",
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8"
```

to be used in `headerin` option of `proc http`.

But i am still not able to connect.

Can anyone help me to write correct syntax for `headerin=` option. 
how to seperate 2 oprions in `headerin=`(is key out here).

Comment: You'll get more detailed and specific answers if you specify exactly the code you use.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have 9.4 you can very easily apply multiple headers; see [this paper](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings16/SAS6363-2016.pdf) for example:

```
proc http
 url="http://httpbin.org/headers"
 out=out;
headers
 "My-Header"="my value"
 "Another-Header"="my second value";
run;
```

And so forth.

Second, the `headerin` option points to a fileref that you can create (either by hand or via code) containing the header you need.  See the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/70377/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0bdg5vmrpyi7jn1pbgbje2atoov.htm) for more details about this.

```
filename headfile "c:\temp\my_headers.txt";

proc http
 url="http://httpbin.org/headers"
 out=out
 headerin=headfile;
run;
```

If you have 9.4 TS1M3 or later, you should use the first syntax.  If you have an earlier version, use the second syntax (as the first won't work).

Comment: thanks Joe, i tried the second syntax of using the txt file. but it is not working.  can you tell me how to seperate the multple headers. I tried with new line,comma etc but couldnt work.                                            X-SFDC-Session: 00D4E00000090Mu!ARIAQM143scGYiI3puNevW.pZgfsxBPXZcgVuulkqf2yGHXDGUZ2XIO2_naZqwaTi3bPxpjCBunKK7VeV7boHp.uk7KYhiok
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: From doc: `HEADERIN
specifies a fileref to a text file that contains one line per request header in the format key:value.`

Comment: Your issue may be `"`; it may not want those.  You should talk to your Salesforce admin as this really gets into what they want, not what SAS wants.

Answer (score 0):

With connected app you can generate oAuth token using PROC HTTP and use it to pass SOQL from SAS to Salesforce.

[Here is a link for SAS Access to Sales force via rest api](https://myweirdcodes.com/sas-access-to-salesforce-via-rest-api/)